# using pivot function on date column in python

Tags: python, database, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset like :

```
Date(in ddmmyyyy)
1-2-20
2-2-20
3-2-20
```

On using

```
df.pivot(columns='date',index='state',values='case')
```

Dates get arranged in columns like .

```
1-2-20   
1-3-20   
1-4-20
```

like 1st of everymonth  , then second of everymonth ... I want it in original order like 1st of feb , 2nd of feb ....

Comment: before pivot, use `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True)`

Comment: @QuangHoang I used  df = pd.read_csv("testt2.csv",dayfirst=True,parse_dates=[0]) , it converted the dtype of date column to datetime but it is now in yyyymmdd . on using to_datetime function dates in the main column get shuffled up .. I tried converting date column to ddmmyyyy but it get converted to string and then pivot function on date column don't work properly .